# I can't install pip mysql-connector

Tags: python, mysql, installation, pip

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects> pip install mysql-connector
Collecting mysql-connector
  Using cached mysql-connector-2.2.9.tar.gz (11.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [38 lines of output]
      Warning: 'keywords' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\beek6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ck6wv7i\mysql-connector_785864700b6f4aa5a9ea85383040de83\setup.py", line 53, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 147, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 496, in __init__
          _Distribution.__init__(
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 283, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 934, in finalize_options
          for ep in sorted(loaded, key=by_order):
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 933, in <lambda>
          loaded = map(lambda e: e.load(), filtered)
                                 ^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\beek6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 202, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\beek6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\py2app\build_app.py", line 37, in <module>
          from py2app.create_appbundle import create_appbundle
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\py2app\create_appbundle.py", line 9, in <module>
          from py2app.util import make_exec, makedirs, mergecopy, mergetree, skipscm
        File "C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\py2app\util.py", line 5, in <module>
          import fcntl
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
(venv) PS C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects>
```

Comment: Please add some additional info. How did you create this venv? Was it copied from a Mac machine by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to `mysql-connector`. You have installed `py2app` on your Windows but https://pypi.org/project/py2app/ is only for Mac OS X. Uninstall `py2app`:

```
pip uninstall -y py2app
```

or remove the directory `C:\Users\beek6\PycharmProjects\Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\py2app`